# C# JOIN vs. Stored Procedure in Sql Server, Which one brings a better performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Let me change the question like this:

Which one of the below modes would increase the performance of an application?

1. A method in C# which performs about 6 JOIN statements and returns a value.
2. An stored procedure which performs 6 JOIN statements

Which of the above would be more efficient in terms of application performance?

Here is the Code:

```
public bool UserHasAccess(string userName, string actionName)
    {
        var decodedUserName = UtilityHands.GeneralTools.DecodeString(userName);
        using (MAHAL_E_MA_Repository.UnitOfWork unit = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var theUserID = unit.UserRepository.Get(filter: s => s.UserName.Equals(decodedUserName)).First().ID;
            var userInRoleGroup = unit.RoleGroupUserRepository.Get(filter: r => r.UserInRole == theUserID).ToList();

            var roleInRoleGroups = unit.RoleOfRoleGroupRepository.Get().ToList();
            var serviceOfRoles = unit.ServiceOfRoleRepository.Get().ToList();
            var serviceOfAction = unit.ServiceOfActionRepository.Get().ToList();
            var roles = unit.RoleRepository.Get().ToList();
            var service = unit.ServiceRepository.Get().ToList();
            var actions = unit.ActionProviderRepository.Get().ToList();

            var rolesOfRoleGroupJoin = userInRoleGroup.Join(roleInRoleGroups,
                                            (u => u.RoleGroupID),
                                            (r => r.RoleGroupID),
                                            ((u, r) => new { userInRoleGroup = u, roleInRoleGroups = r }));

            var rrgOfRolesJoin = rolesOfRoleGroupJoin.Join(roles,
                                                      (r => r.roleInRoleGroups.RoleID),
                                                      (rs => rs.RoleID),
                                                      ((r, rs) => new { rolesOfRoleGroupJoin = r, roles = rs }));

            var roleServiceJoin = rrgOfRolesJoin.Join(serviceOfRoles,
                                                    (rrg => rrg.roles.RoleID),
                                                    (sor => sor.RoleID),
                                                    ((rrg, sor) => new { rrgOfRolesJoin = rrg, serviceOfRoles = sor }));

            var serviceOfRolesServiceJoin = roleServiceJoin.Join(service,
                                                                (rs => rs.serviceOfRoles.ServiceID),
                                                                (s => s.ServiceID),
                                                                ((rs, s) => new { roleServiceJoin = rs, service = s }));

            var serviceActionJoin = serviceOfRolesServiceJoin.Join(serviceOfAction,
                                                                  (sors => sors.service.ServiceID),
                                                                  (soa => soa.ServiceID),
                                                                  ((sors, soa) => new { serviceOfRolesServiceJoin = sors, serviceOfAction = soa }));

            var serviceActionWithActionJoin = serviceActionJoin.Join(actions,
                                                                    (sa => sa.serviceOfAction.ActionProviderID),
                                                                    (a => a.ActionProviderID),
                                                                    ((sa, a) => new { serviceActionJoin = sa, actions = a }));

            var actionNames = serviceActionWithActionJoin.Where(s => s.actions.Description.Equals(actionName));

            if (actionNames != null && actionNames.Count() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you need the _result_ of the method repeatedly? That's normally what one caches, not the method itself.

Comment: "Cached" for what duration or under what circumstances?  Do you just need the method on any given instance of the object to only make the call once and internally store the result?  You can store the result in a private field on the object and check for a value in that field any time the method is called.  If there's a value, return it.  If there isn't, perform the logic and store the result and return it.

Comment: @Oded: You are write I just mean which one of the ways mentioned on the question above would assist the application performance most?

Comment: You want to cache the result/output of said method. More info: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Cache-Exploration-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Part-1.aspx

Comment: @David: You explained very clearly. But I need to know which one of the ways mentioned in the question is better than the other in terms of performance?

Comment: @user2394196: There isn't enough information to know which of those two would perform better.  How expensive are the join statements?  Are the objects internally accessing other resources?  If you just need to measure the performance of two options in your code then run them both and measure the performance, rather than have us guess for you.  Optimize based on actual numbers, not on conjecture from people who don't know your code.

Comment: @David: To be frank, you are write! I apologize for not providing enough information. I will keep suggestions in mind and try to figure it out once more. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that with "`A method in C# which performs about 6 JOIN statements and returns a value." you are doing it in Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities that translates all the joins to *one* query that hits the database.

In that case, there will be no noticable differences. The query execution plan is cached in the same way for both SPs and dynamically generated queries (SPs used to have better performance, but that difference is removed since several years).

If you are doing the join "in memory" by retrieving separate results from the DB you will get much, much worse performance.

Comment: @Andres: That is right.. I'm doing Linq-To-Entities and it is good if there is no specific difference between the two ways, Thank you, By the way I have added the C# Code too so that if you may have any additional comment I would be grateful!

Comment: With the code you're using, you are retrieving *all* the data for all tables before doing the join. That's awfully slow.

Comment: Yes... :( That is a bad practice! I feel better if writing a stored proc.. Thanks again